# Objects in a UITableViewCell are not aligning with autoresizing

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have an App which I do not use Auto Layout. I only use the Autoresizing constrains to adjust the position of the objects on different devices display sizes.

I have a table view in my app with static cells and I've added a couple of switches and a custom button but the constrains aren't working inside the cell.

Example:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTGWM.png)

As you can see, the switch has a locked constrain to the right but it's not aligning to the right.

Is this a bug of Xcode 8? Is there an workaround?

Comment: you must to work with autolayout, and set correct constraints there to achieve what you need, check this tutorial this can help you https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: @ReinierMelian I will try to work with autolayout in my future apps, but I've already made this one without it. The autoresizing works in every other screen I've made on the app, except inside the tableview cell.